# Https URL without slash is redirected to http version with DirectorySlash On

Tags: http, https, 301-redirect, apache2

We have a VM running with our hosting provider where the following issue occurs...

When accessing `https://www.app.com/folder-on-filesystem` Apache sends a redirect (301) to the URL with a trailing slash because `DirectorySlash On`. Problem is that it redirects to the http version or the URL: `http://www.app.com/folder-on-filesystem/`. We have started noticing this when we wanted to display our app in an iframe (yes, an iframe!) on a client's website that run on https.

So , in short:

```
GET https://www.app.com/folder-on-filesystem

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Redirect to: http://www.app.com/folder-on-filesystem/
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are there any rewrite rules in .htaccess? Plus, is you pit an HTTP iframe in a HTTPS page the browser will complain with "This page contains both secure and insecure items".

Comment: Could you give some indication of what the apache config causing this actually looks like? And, as @Gmck suggested, check/provide any relevant htaccess files that could be inducing the behaviour.